# Using Pandas to create a Q&A chatbot in LLamaIndex

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api, langchain, llama-index

Currently I have a Database with Questions on column A and answers on column B.

I Want to create a chatbot that takes the user’s question, searches the most similar question on Column A and outputs its correspondent answer from column B.

I tried doing this with Vector, keyword and tree indexes. but when I ask for example question 1, it outputs answer 2.
or sometimes it combines answer 1 and 3 for example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au2FV.png)

I tried to create a pandas index and it works very well only if the user’s question is exactly the same as a question from column A.

if i change a word only a little, an error appears and says that I am trying to look outside the range of the table.

So my question is:

Is a pandas index the right index for this kind of cases?
if not? what is the most suited index format in this case? and how can I ensure to reply always right?

my code for the pandas index is:

```
import logging
import sys
import os
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))

from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader
from IPython.display import Markdown, display


from llama_index.indices.struct_store import GPTPandasIndex
import pandas as pd


os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ''


col_names = ['Question','Answer']
df = pd.read_csv("Q&A.csv", names = col_names)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
index = GPTPandasIndex(df=df)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(
    verbose=True
)
response = query_engine.query(
    "/question from my database",
)
print (response)`
```